What's previnting me access to camera for videoconferencing?
I recently reinstall Ubuntu 24.04. However, it appears I cannot use the camera for videoconferencing. I suspect some process holding up the camera. Google Meet and Jitsi report that camera Microphone are in use. My last meeting was just fine with microphone, I aplogised to other participants, I can't enabled webcam.
Googole Meet:

address bar:


camera status (from the buttom):



Jitsi:

zoom:

Vedio screen is completely dark in all cases. Troubleshooting to see if this can be fixed easily:

Check process(es) using the camera:

$ lsof /dev/video*
$ 

NO process seems using the camera.

camera permissions:

$ ls -l /dev/video*
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 Dec 10 10:04 /dev/video0
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 1 Dec 10 10:04 /dev/video1
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 2 Dec 10 10:04 /dev/video2
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 3 Dec 10 10:04 /dev/video3


I can see that I (current user) have access to the camera:

$ groups
my_user_name adm cdrom sudo dip video plugdev users lpadmin


restarted camera.

$ sudo modprobe -r uvcvideo
$ sudo modprobe uvcvideo


Tested webcam using cheese:

$ cheese

Completely dark as well.

cheese's log:
$ cheese
[7:18:25.811580714] [45550]  WARN IPAManager ipa_manager.cpp:154 No IPA found in '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcamera'
[7:18:25.811708525] [45550]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:284 libcamera v0.2.0

(cheese:45550): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 18:10:22.243: gst_structure_get_value: assertion 'structure != NULL' failed
[7:18:25.917844432] [45550]  WARN IPAManager ipa_manager.cpp:154 No IPA found in '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcamera'
[7:18:25.917914196] [45550]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:284 libcamera v0.2.0
[7:18:26.016129417] [45581]  INFO Camera camera.cpp:1183 configuring streams: (0) 1920x1080-MJPEG
[7:18:26.041839655] [45581]  WARN IPAManager ipa_manager.cpp:154 No IPA found in '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcamera'
[7:18:26.041913707] [45581]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:284 libcamera v0.2.0
[7:18:26.112822320] [45580]  INFO Camera camera.cpp:1183 configuring streams: (0) 1920x1080-MJPEG

** (cheese:45550): WARNING **: 18:10:22.546: could not generate thumbnail for /home/akil/Videos/Webcam/2024-12-06-222319.webm (video/webm): Could not find thumbnailer for mime-type 'video/webm'


** (cheese:45550): WARNING **: 18:10:22.551: could not generate thumbnail for /home/akil/Videos/Webcam/2024-12-06-222550.webm (video/webm): Could not find thumbnailer for mime-type 'video/webm'


Info:
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Release:        24.04
Codename:       noble

What's going on here?
